# IndexOutOfRangeException when retrieving models from repository

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm getting this exception:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at lambda_method(Closure , ValueBuffer )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalMixedEntityEntry..ctor(IStateManager stateManager, IEntityType entityType, Object entity, ValueBuffer& valueBuffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryFactory.NewInternalEntityEntry(IStateManager stateManager, IEntityType entityType, Object entity, ValueBuffer& valueBuffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTrackingFromQuery(IEntityType baseEntityType, Object entity, ValueBuffer& valueBuffer, ISet`1 handledForeignKeys)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityTrackingInfo.StartTracking(IStateManager stateManager, Object entity, ValueBuffer& valueBuffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.StartTracking(Object entity, EntityTrackingInfo entityTrackingInfo)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`2.<_TrackEntities>b__0(TOut result)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Select.cs:line 109
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\AsyncIterator.cs:line 98
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery[TResult](QueryContext queryContext, Func`2 compiledQuery, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Type contextType)
   at SuperChrono.Api.Controllers.UpdateController.GetAsync(Int32 id) in C:\Users\Albert\source\repos\Superchrono 2.0-v2\SuperChrono.Api\Controllers\UpdateController.cs:line 31
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIIndexMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Here's how `UpdateController.GetAsync()` looks like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(int id)
{
    var update = await _updateRepository.GetAsync(id); // 31st line
    if (update == null)
        return NotFound();

    return Ok(new Responses.UpdateResponse { Update = update });
}
```

Here's the repository `GetAsync()`:

```
public Task<Update> GetAsync(int id)
{
    return _db.Updates.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
}
```

...where `_db` is my `DbContext`. That's how it looks:

```
public class SuperChronoContext : DbContext
{
    // (...)
    public DbSet<Update> Updates { get; set; }

    public SuperChronoContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        // (...)

        builder.Entity<Update>()
            .Property<int>("ProjectId")
            .HasColumnName("id_ProjectNode");
        builder.Entity<Update>()
            .Property<int>("UserId")
            .HasColumnName("id_User");
        builder.Entity<Update>()
            .Property<int>("TypeId")
            .HasColumnName("id_UpdateType");
    }
}
```

That's how the model looks like:

```
public class Update
{
    [Column("id_Update")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Duration of work on update in minutes.
    /// </summary>
    [Column("usedTime"), Required]
    public int Time { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Additional duration of work on update in minutes.
    /// </summary>
    [Column("additionalTime"), Required]
    public int AdditionalTime { get; set; }
    [Column("updateDate", TypeName = "smalldatetime"), Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Column("creationDate", TypeName = "smalldatetime"), Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Column("id_ProjectNode"), Required]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    //public virtual Project Project { get;set; }
    [Column("id_User"), Required]
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
    [Column("id_UpdateType"), Required]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    //public virtual ProjectType Type { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, here's how my table looks like:

[image: table structure]

---

And I don't know where is my problem. I tried solutions I found on the Internet, but they just didn't help.

I have other models in my code and they work just fine. All code fetching those models from database throws me this error, not only `GetAsync(int id)` but also some other that does `_db.Updates.ToListAsync()`.

Unit tests using an `InMemoryDatabase` pass just fine.

I'm struggling with this for the second day now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `OnModelCreating` you declare :

```
builder.Entity<Update>()
            .Property<int>("UserId")
            .HasColumnName("id_User");
```

But in your `Update` class you have:

```
[Column("id_User"), Required]
public int OwnerId { get; set; }
```

`UserId` is not a property of your model.

A good way to avoid this kind of problems in the future is to use `.Property(u => u.OwnerId)` instead.

Comment: And I'm just asking myself "...really? :|". Thanks! If only Microsoft did a better job in providing meaningful error messages...

Comment: personaly I prefer to use `.Property(u => u.OwnerId)` to avoid this kind of issue while refactoring

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I didn't know about that, will use it :)